# Django 1.10.0 LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL NOT Working

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have been using the default django auth for login and I am also using the decorator `@login_required` for some of the pages. There is no need to remember the previous page if the user hits logout and stuff. The idea is, the user will be redirected to a static page once logged in. How do I do that in django? I do not want to edit login template.

```
LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/' #redirects the user to the login page if not logged in already

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/something-else' #does not work.
```

In my urlconf, it's defined like

```
url(r'^something-else/$', views.something_else, name='something-else')
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried appending a "/" to your `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` setting?  Also, do you have `APPEND_SLASH` set to True and CommonMiddleware defined in your settings? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#append-slash

Comment: @ARJMP Thanks for your reply. I have CommonMiddleware defined in the settings and ` APPEND_SLASH ` is set to True. No luck yet.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens after you log in?

Comment: @Selcuk I end up in the 'Site Administration' page, rather I want it to be redirected to another page when the user is logged in.